# Firebase UI unable to resolve dependency

Tags: android, firebase

I added this: `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'` to the app file but it showed me these errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0.
```

I have tried cleaning the project and restarted Android Studio, but still getting the errors. Any ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: What version of gradle you are using? Update it to: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` then try.

Comment: Yep it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to root `Build.gradle` and update your `gradle` to v `3.2.0`:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // keep this updated too

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

And then rebuild the project. This happens because maybe you were using older `gradle` versions and it couldn't find it with that. So, updating the gradle will help.